# using case inside the ON clause of a join

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a question: what is the right way to use a CASE statement in the ON clause of a JOIN?
(I saw a couple of similar questions had been asked by others, but I don't see how to replicate the solutions in my scenario.)

I try to connect 2 instances of the same table (self join).
The table contains a balance value of each customer for each day (row per customer per day, each customer appears multiple times- since the first day of his activity and till he/she closes the account)

[image]

For each customer i need to find what is the balance today and in another column - what was the balance on the "base date". The default for the base date  is the 31 -dec-2019 **BUT** if the customer comes from a specific branch (BRANCH "X") then the base date should be 31-mar-2020 (instead of 31-dec-2019).
So what I'm trying to do is to write something like this:

```
select 
B.branch_name,
B.customer_id,
B.balance as current_balance,
B1.balance as base_date_balance,
from 
balance B inner join balance B1
on B.customer_id=B1.customer_id
and B.date = '20apr2020'
and B1.date= (case when B.branch_name = 'X' then '31-mar-2020' else '31-dec-2019' end)
```

I get that this is not the right way to do this, but I can't figure it out what the right way is. 
Thanks in advance for all the answers and the help, highly appreciate ! :)

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: It's just part of the predicate, as any other predicate. Nothing special.

Comment: Your query looks correct. I would use ISO format for the dates (like "2020-03-31") but, apart from that, it's OK.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions!:

```
select b.*,
       max(case when branch = 'B' and date = date '2019-03-31' then balance
                when date = date '2019-12-31' then balance
           end) over (partition by customer_id, branch_name
                     ) as base_date_balance
from balance b;
```

This should have better performance than a `JOIN` with an `OR` or `CASE` condition.

Alternatively, the `join` would look like:

```
from b join
     b bbase
     on bbase.customer_id = b.customer_id and
        bbase.branch_name = b.branch_name and
        ( (bbase.branch_name = 'B' and bbase.date = date '2019-03-31') or
          (bbase.branch_name <> 'B' and bbase.date = date '2019-12-31')
        )
```

Comment: I think you might need some extra parens in the join version.  Doesn't `or` have higher precedence than `and`?

Comment: @DaveCosta . . . No.  The parentheses aren't needed but I'll put them in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select b.* from table
where rownum=1
and date<(select date from table where cust=... order by date desc) 
order by date desc
```

This will give you the previous transaction according to the criteria. The subquery returns the latest transaction.

The next step will depend on the database. On Oracle you use:

```
Select (select latest_transactions)-(select previous_tranaction) from dual.
```

If you need more info let me know. I am writing from my phone.